# A girl and a guy

Tags: wordplay, science

The main goal here is to **figure out the one-“word” answer to each of the following clues**.

Each answer consists of **one (or more) names and one (or more) other words** hinted at by the clues.  There is, of course, **a gimmick** that links all the answers together.  Once you get one right, it should be clear what the gimmick is and make the rest much easier.

```
1.  Green guy
2.  Girl you get your illicit prescription drugs from
3.  Compete and guy
4.  Girl poem
5.  Break guy out of jail
6.  Web publication about a guy
7.  Girl (plus the first of her last) and basic substance
8.  Fib and guy
9.  Either of two quarters of a bubbly beverage and guy
10. Flaky thin dough and girl
11. Guy and 1982 movie
12. Church noisemaker and girl
13. First letter and guy
14. Greek letter and guy
15. Greek letter and guy
16. Guy and greek letter and extent
17. Guy atop
18. HVAC fixture named after guy
19. One tenth of girl
20. Possible 1980 slogan for a guy
21. Guy and meditative utterance
22. Perfectly round (except the last) girl
23. Guy and charged ocean denizen
24. Fermented honey and guy
25. Girl and seaperson prefix and guy
26. Formerly guy
27. Guy and dream stage
28. Extremely girl
29. Guy and what you make before shopping (with its indefinite article)
30. Tear apart Johann Maier von and guy
```

---

If I stopped there, this might be pretty obscure, so here are the **second set of clues**.  Solving each of these will provide you with **one of the guy or girl names** you can use to answer the clues above.  Note that each clue will lead to a name, but the precise form of that name that is used in the above clue might vary (e.g., “Dan” vs. “Danny”).  And also the order of these clues does not match the order of the first set...that would be too obvious.

---

```
He knows when to walk away, and he knows when to run
Speaker, candidate, lizard
She never was an anti-masturbation breakfast cereal girl
He was a controversial scientist, a cowboy, a producer, and a chocolate maven
Pet detective
Poor Richard, really
He won three, took a couple years off, then won three more
He was sure about the boundlessness of stupidity
He was a Pharaoh, a King, and a General all in the same year
Peace-train-era Yusuf
She was a good girl and a friend
He revealed that guys like their balls round, tacky, brand new, thin, or old
She chewed, became inflated, then had to be juiced
His name was Gladiator, though his real last name’s a bird
You can pickup a dress or a top from her loft
She wants a cracker
HR king
He can feel it, coming in the air tonight
Libertarian who made a case for gold
A feral girl, portrayed by Hinckley’s obsession
The voice of Hercules
It’s likely the one on his mind was not the one with Tbilisi
You’d better call him
Voice of an adorable carapace
Animated Beast’s love interest
He links It’s My Party and Beat It
Bond maker
She authored one of the world’s best-read diaries
He suggests that you limit your eagerness
The D in SCDP
He directed submission, and his great-granduncle depicted a wondrous evening
```

Note that you don't really need to solve the second list to complete the first list, but it may help.

Since there are a lot of clues, partial answers and collaboration are welcome.

**FOR A BONUS**: Figure out an answer to the post’s title that fits the gimmick.

Good luck!

Comment: Can the name and word parts overlap? For example, could 14 be just "Phil" (phi / Phil)?

Comment: @KeyboardWielder No, both parts are present in each answer, though the sounds may overlap a bit.

Comment: Are you sure about the voice of a carapace?  Normally shells don't talk on their own... :)

Comment: @axavio This carapace is on YouTube, talking and walking with the help of some animation and voiceover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Community wiki

Complete and submitted for inspection...

### Second set

> Pet detective - **Ace Ventura [25]**
>  His name was Gladiator, though his real last name’s a bird - **Russell Crowe [3]** (Maximus Decimus Meridius in *Gladiator*)
>  She wants a cracker - **Polly [25]**
>  She authored one of the world’s best-read diaries - **Anne Frank [4]**
>  The D in SCDP -> **Don Draper [9]** (mad men)
>  He links It’s My Party and Beat It -> **Quincy Jones [5]** (producer)
>  You’d better call him -> **Saul [18]**
>  The voice of Hercules -> **Tate Donovan [14]**
>  He can feel it, coming in the air tonight -> **Phil Collins [1]**
>  Peace-train-era Yusuf -> **Cat Stevens [29]**
>  Poor Richard, really -> **Benjamin Franklin [6]** (poor richard's almanac)
>  He knows when to walk away, and he knows when to run -> **Kenny Rogers [8]** (the gambler)
>  Animated Beast’s love interest -> **Belle [19]** (or Paige O'Hara)
>  He suggests that you limit your eagerness -> **Larry David [15]**
>  Bond maker -> **Ian Fleming [24]**
>  It’s likely the one on his mind was not the one with Tbilisi -> **Ray Charles [26]**
>  She chewed, became inflated, then had to be juiced -> **Violet Beauregarde [28]**
>  A feral girl, portrayed by Hinckley’s obsession -> **Nell [12]**
>  She never was an anti-masturbation breakfast cereal girl -> **Tori Amos [22]**
>  Voice of an adorable carapace -> **Jenny [10]**
>  He was a controversial scientist, a cowboy, a producer, and a chocolate maven -> **Gene Wilder [21]**
>  Speaker, candidate, lizard -> **Newt Gingrich [11]**
>  He was a Pharaoh, a King, and a General all in the same year -> **Yul Brynner [30]**
>  HR King -> **Barry Bonds [17]**
>  He was sure about the boundlessness of stupidity -> **Al(bert) Einstein [23]**
>  You can pickup a dress or a top from her loft -> **Ann Taylor [7]**
>  Libertarian who made a case for gold -> **Ron Paul [20]**
>  He revealed that guys like their balls round, tacky, brand new, thin, or old  -> **Tom Brady [13]**
>  He won three, took a couple years off, then won three more -> **Michael Jordan [16]**  (Mike?)
>  She was a good girl and a friend -> **Jennifer Anniston [2]**
>  He directed submission, and his great-granduncle depicted a wondrous evening -> **Theo van Gogh [27]**

### First set

Solved:

> 1.  Green guy - **Chlorophyll** (it's a green Phil)
>  2.  Girl you get your illicit prescription drugs from - **Oxygen** (Oxy(contin) + Jen)
>  3.  Compete and guy - **Virus** (Vie + Russ(ell))
>  4.  Girl poem - **Anode**  (Anne + ode)
>  5.  Break guy out of jail **Frequency** (free + Quincy)
>  6.  Web publication about a guy - **Benzene** (Ben(jamin) + Zine)
>  7.  Girl (plus the first of her last) and basic substance - **Anti-matter** (Ann T. + Matter)
>  8.  Fib and guy - **Lichen** (Lie + Ken)
> 9.  Either of two quarters of a bubbly beverage and guy. **Codon** (Co (a quarter of Coca Cola) + Don)
>  10. Flaky thin dough and girl - **Phylogeny**  (phyllo or filo + Jenny)
>  11. Guy and 1982 movie - **Neutron**  (Newt + Tron)
>  12. Church noisemaker and girl - **Organelle** (Organ + Nell)
>  13. First letter and guy - **Atom** (A + Tom)
>  14. Greek letter and guy - **Mutate** ($\mu$ + Tate)
>  15. Greek letter and guy - **Capillary** (Kappa + Larry)
>  16. Guy and greek letter and extent - **Microscope** (Mike + rho + scope)
>  17. Guy atop - **Baryon** (Barry + on)
>  18. HVAC fixture named after a guy - **Solvent** (Saul + vent)
>  19. One tenth of girl - **Decibel**  (Deci- + Belle)
>  20. Possible 1980 slogan for a guy - **Electron** (Elect Ron! (Reagan)). 
>   - **Frequency** (Free Quincy!)
>  21. Guy and meditative utterance - **Genome** (Gene + Om)
>  22. Perfectly round (except the last) girl - **Circulatory** (Circular - 'r' + Tori)
>  23. Guy and charged ocean denizen - **Allele** (Al + Eel)
>  24. Fermented honey and guy - **Median** (Mead + Ian)
>  25. Girl and seaperson prefix and guy - **Polymerase** (Polly + mer + Ace)
>  26. Formerly guy - **X-Ray** (Ex + Ray)
>  27. Guy and dream stage - **Theorem** (Theo + REM)
>  28. Extremely girl - **Ultraviolet** (Ultra- + Violet)
>  29. Guy and what you make before shopping (with its indefinite article) - **Catalyst** [Cat + a list]
>  30. Tear apart Johann Maier von and guy - **Molecule** (Maul + Eck + Yul)

The gimmick, of course, has to be:

> Words related to **science**

FOR A BONUS: An answer to the post’s title that fits the gimmick:

> **Anatomy** (Anna + Tommy)
>  **Marinate** (Mary + Nate) *[not really science, I guess]*

Comment: All answers thus far to the second set look good! First set needs some work, but it's a good start.

Comment: Polymerase is good. Ligase would require someone named Gase, so not correct.

Comment: If only there was Guy and Guy, there'd be Solution with Saul and Lucien.

Comment: @WesleySitu There's a bunch that passed through my mind but I didn't post here. Fun to come up with these. And, by the way, you're actually quite close to a real one with that example!

Comment: Could 11 in the second set be neutron (Newt + tron)? Possibly Newt Gingrich in the second set, as he's the only well known Newt that comes to mind.

Comment: Gamma ray for greek letter and a guy?

Comment: For the title, I'm thinking "anatomy" (Anna + Tommy) ?

Comment: The "He won three" in the second set is likely Michael Jordan - three NBA rings, then a few years off, then three more.

Comment: And 12 in the first could be "organelle" (Organ + Elle).

Comment: Great work, all! Iris is wrong on the second set. GeneOm is right. Neuron is not what I had in mind for 15...you'll need Ron elsewhere. @mdc32 is right about Mike and #12, though the girl name in #12 is not quite right.

Comment: "Voice of an adorable carapace" could be either Marcel, Dean, or Jenny. Thanks to OP's comment on the question, I believe it is a reference to "Marcel the Shell" on YouTube, who is created by a man named Dean and voiced by a woman Jenny.

Comment: The director of Submission for set 2 is Theo van Gogh, whose great-granduncle was Vincent, who painted _Starry Night_.

Comment: The "Elle" from "organelle" could come from Elizabeth Olsen, who was in Very Good Girls. Not sure about the friend part though.

Comment: I would think that "a good girl and a friend" would be Jennifer Aniston. She was in the movie The Good Girl and the series Friends.

Comment: The feral girl is Nell, from the movie of the same name. I believe that should be the name for #12. I would edit this stuff in, but I'm on a phone, atm, and I don't wanna mess things up.

Comment: #30 is sheer genius.

Comment: Leftover clues and remaining names all seem good. Just remember that different versions of each name can be used (Mike vs. Michael, e.g.).

Comment: Could one of them be "chlorophyll"? I don't really know which one that fits, but seeing Phil makes me think that's the case.

Comment: All I got right now: "Co" could be either of two quarters of a bubbly beverage (Coca Cola).

Comment: Almost done! The answer for #20 should actually be the answer for #5. And I actually had a different (also element) in mind for #2. So just have Ron left for #20...

Comment: @DanRussell: ok. Fixed 5, 2 and 20 per your suggestion. Only #20 to go!

Comment: All done (I think...)  great job team!

Comment: Boom! Nice job everyone! The other bonus one I had in mind (in addition to AnnaTommy) was PollyNate.